# on question 1 or in question 1

Tags: prepositions

Suppose you have to make up sentences using a certain grammar structure on a test. I want to talk about someone else's answers on specific questions. Is it...

On question 1

In question 2

You repeated the example as a sentence on question 1.

On questions 2 and 3 you used the wrong verb tense.

Or should I reword it completely?

Thanks for answering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "on" fits better meaning "on the subject of question 1". The word "in" fits better meaning "occurring in question 1", or in its answer, if that is what is meant.

The comments would be understood with either "on" or "in", though.

Since you've invited rewording, these might work:
*For* question 1, you repeated the example as a sentence.
*In* your answers to questions 2 and 3, you used the wrong verb tense.